# "Each" vs "a" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, articles

Is there any difference between "each" and "a" in the following context? It is assumed that there is a game that consists of several levels and we need to describe the objective of each level.

> To finish each level, you need to collect all the orbs and get to the exit door.

or

> To finish a level, you need to collect all the orbs and get to the exit door.

Comment: No semantic difference. There is a pragmatic difference; no people will spend a few seconds just convincing themselves that 'a' here actually is equivalent to 'each'.

Comment: Using ***each*** strongly implies there are a known (finite) number of different members of the relevant class (***levels***, here). Which will often *further* imply that ***each and every one of them*** will be addressed (in turn) by the contextually relevant process (collecting the orbs, here). Using the simple indefinite article *(**a, an**)* carries no such implication (but the *context* might force that interpretation anyway).

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. Everything else being equal, **a** means just a single, random level, but **each** implies all of them (whether it's ***finishing*** all of them, or ***how*** they are all able to be finished, is completely open to interpretation). In sort, **a level** (and only *a level*) means ***one of the levels***.